# Access violation in Image destructor

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, gdi+, access-violation

A very simple program I might say..

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR cmdLine, int nShow){
    // Gdiplus variables
    GdiplusStartupInput mGdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           mGdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&mGdiplusToken, &mGdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Bitmap bitmap(L"left.bmp");


    GdiplusShutdown(mGdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

When running this example I get an access violation in GdiplusBitmap.h in this function

```
inline 
Image::~Image()
{
    DllExports::GdipDisposeImage(nativeImage);
}
```

By removing the call to `Bitmap bitmap(L"left.bmp");` everything works fine.. I tried to find a simple example on msdn (for instance somewhere near the [Bitmap constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536316(VS.85).aspx), but didn't find anything.)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Bitmap` instance you created is falling out of scope AFTER the call to shutdown GDI+. So when the `Bitmap` gets destructed, it cannot call the given `GdipDisposeImage` method.

The error should go away if you make sure that `bitmap` is deleted before you shutdown GDI+.

Comment: +1 this. Add a pair of parenthesis around the bitmap to force it out of scope, or make it a pointer type (ugly).

Comment: That makes sense. But how do I explicitly destroy a bitmap that is created on the stack?

Comment: @Mike: so kind of a block scope around the Bitmap call.. That actually solved it. sweet :) Thanks for the quick replies

Comment: @Michael: Yup. By limiting the scope of where your objects are bound, you can force them off the deep end ;)