# App Verifier Stop 0202: Freeing heap block containing an active critical section during GdiPlusShutdown

Tags: gdi+, application-verifier

When running the [Microsoft Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028) i would get an error `0202` on shutdown:

```
VERIFIER STOP 00000202:
   pid 0x1160: Freeing heap block containing an active critical section. 
   11456F48 : Critical section address.
   047D05B4 : Critical section initialization stack trace.
   11456F40 : Heap block...(cut off)
```

The error would happen while calling [`GdiplusShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

From the Application Verifier documentation:

> ### Freeing heap block containing an active critical section
>
> **Application Verifier break message**
>
> Freeing heap block containing an active critical section. Memory location at  of size  contains an active lock.
>
> **Probable cause**
>
> This break is generated if a heap allocation contains a critical section, the allocation is freed and the critical section has not been deleted.
>
> **Information displayed by Application Verifier**
>
> - Parameter1 - Critical section address
> - Parameter2 - Critical section initialization stack trace
> - Parameter3 - Heap block address
> - Parameter4 - Heap block size
> - Description - Freeing heap block containing an active critical section
>
> **Additional information**
>
> Verifier stop code 0202.
>
> Check the contents of the current call stack. The culprit is usually the caller of HeapFree or HeapDestroy on the current stack trace.
>
> Frequency of this error is high.
>
> To debug this stop use the following debugger commands:
>
> - `!cs –s parameter1` - dump information about this critical section.
> - `ln parameter1` – to show symbols near the address of the critical section. This should help identify the leaked critical section.
> - `dds parameter2` – to dump the stack trace for this critical section initialization.
>
> **parameter3** and **parameter4** might help understand where was this heap block allocated (the size of the allocation is probably significant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this error a few months ago and i'd forgotten the solution.

Be sure to free any GDI+ Images (e.g. [`GdipDisposeImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534041%28VS.85%29.aspx)) before trying to shutdown GDI+.

Otherwise you leak a Critical Section, and who knows what else. And certainly don't try to [dispose an image *after* GDI+ has already been shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354136/access-violation-in-image-destructor).